# Is anything to be gained by deleting old workflow runs in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions

My (commercial) Github project has many hundreds of old actions workflow runs. I'm certain we will never need anything but the last few weeks worth of them. I'm just wondering if there's any point deleting them? Do they take up space in some bucket we are paying for somewhere? Or are they effectively free?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save money according to https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions